# Find if points are within a circle with given center and radius

Tags: geometry

We have a point **(x,y)** and a set of some other points **(xi,yi)**. How can we determine which of **(xi,yi)** are within a circle with center **(x,y)** and radius **r** (a given number)?

Comment: psasik:  Probably because it's borderline not a programming question.

Answer (score 16):

```
(xi-x)**2 + (yi-y)**2 < r**2
```

Comment: And use <= if you wish to also include points **on** the circle, in addition to those within.

Answer (score 6):

Simple way.

Compute the distance from the point to the center of the circle. If less than radius , then its within the circle.

Answer (score 3):

If (xi - x)^2 + (yi - y)^2 is less than d^2, it's inside.  If it equals d^2, it's on the circle.  If it's greater than d^2, it's outside.

Answer (score 2):

If sqrt((xi-x)^2 + (yi-y)^2) <= d

Comment: you can optimize this. Ommit the SQRT for better performance.

(xi-x)^2 + (yi-y)^2 <= d ^2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to solve inside a plsql procedure. The solution above are completely right and I did the same. But it compromised the performance of my plsql program drastically. Instead of that circle calculation, I used a square. Because it can be done without doing such calculation and in the sql statement itself. It improved the query performance by more than 10x