# Django point distance in given circle

Tags: django, postgresql, geo

I have Django 1.7 with PostgreSQL 9.3 behind.

I want to store a model with geometrical field circle and be able to get true or false if a given point is within the stored geometrical circle. I found that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941236/store-a-circle-in-geodjango-postgres) and that [library](https://github.com/expobrain/django-postgres-geometry) and also this [option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std%3Afieldlookup-dwithin), so I got lost...

What is the right and simpler way to do it, is it better to save a point and a radius and then calculate it (so I need to install the django-postgres-geometry?), or should I update Django and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) extension installed into PostgreSQL to achieve this. This is what Django and Postgres use for spatial calculations.

To check if a point is in a circle you can do the following in the Django shell:

```
   from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
   point = Point(45.3, 34.2, srid=4326) # lon, lat

   # check if point in polygon
   mypoly.contains(point) # this returns True/False
```

Comment: Can I achieve it with my versions of Django and PostgreSQL or should I upgrade?

Comment: @Rada your versions of Django and Postgres are fine - you just need a third library installed into the Postgres database called `PostGIS` http://postgis.net/ This is what Django/Postgres uses for spatial calculations

Comment: @djq- but also I need some library for Django to use circleField in my model? How I suppose to create the field and save it in postgresql?

Comment: I guess I will use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/ :)